# Method of simplifying parabolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I consider PDE for the function $f(x, t)$ of the form:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f_t + Ax^2 f_{xx} + Bx f_{x} + g(x)f + h(x, t) = 0 \\
f(x, T) = 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\times [0, T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

This is very general form of PDE, but I wonder what kind of substitution or other method I can use to simplify it and finally solve.

Comment: The $x$ part looks like a Cauchy-Euler form, so maybe try $x = e^y$?